# Mercurial and TortoiseHG - Update remote repository after pushing changes

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When pushing changes to a remote repository, is it not possible to automatically run update there so the changes/files are available?

Comment: added the hg update command to run remote when pushing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `changegroup` hook on the remote side, as [described in the Mercurial FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F).

Answer (score 0):

Edit .hg/hgrc on the remote repository and add:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.UpdateOnPush = hg update
```