# mercurial: how to update production files without a server (EDIT: workaround + non-MS Windows solution)

Tags: mercurial, share

I need to control the version of a few files accessible via an SMB share. These files will be modified by several people. The files themselves are directly used by a web server.

Since these are production files I wanted to force the users to pull a local copy, edit them, commit and push them back. Unfortunately there is no Mercurial server on that machine.

What would be the appropriate way to configure Mercurial on my side so that:

- the versioning (.hg directory) is kept on the share
- and that the files on the share are at the latest version?

I do not have access to this server (other than via the share). If I could have a mercurial server on that machine I would have used a hook to update the files in the production directory (I am saying this just to highlight what I want to achieve - this approach is not possible as I do not control that server)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I ended up using an intermediate server (which I have control over). A hook on `changegroup` triggers a script which *i)* `hg update` to have fresh local files *ii)* copies them to the SMB share

**EDIT 1** Following discussions in comments with [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis) I have looked at the verbose version of the command line output. The `\\srv\hg\test1` repo has a `[hooks]` section with `changegroup = hg update`. The output from a `hg push -v` gives some insights:

```
pushing to \\srv\hg\test1
query 1; heads
(...)
updating the branch cache
running hook changegroup: hg update
'\\srv\hg\test1'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
abort: no repository found in 'C:\Windows' (.hg not found)!
warning: changegroup hook exited with status 255
checking for updated bookmarks
listing keys for "bookmarks"
```

If I understand correctly the output above:

- a cmd.exe was triggered on the client, even though the `[hook]` was on the receiving server
- it tried to update the remote repo
- ... but failed because UNC are not supported

So [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis)'s answer was correct - it just does not work (yet?) on MS Windows. (Alex please correct me in the comments if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for two things:

1. A repository hook that will automatically update the production repo to the latest version whenever someone pushes to it. This is simple: You're looking for the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6924143/699305)
2. If you can rely on your co-workers to always go through the pull-commit-push process, you're done. If that's not the case, you need a way to prevent people from modifying the production files in place and never committing them.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can selectively withhold write permissions to the checked-out files (but not to the repo) on an SMB share. But you could *discourage* direct modification by making the location of the files less obvious. Perhaps you could direct people to a *second* repository, configured so that everything pushed to it is immediately pushed on to the production repository. This repo need not have a checked-out version of the files at all (create it with `hg clone -U`, or do an `hg update -r 0` afterwards), eliminating the temptation to bypass mercurial.

Comment: This would be the solution I would have used (per my initial post) if I had control over the server -- which would in turn allow me to have a hg server installed there. Unfortunately the only thing I have is an SMB access to a share.

Comment: No no, you don't need a web server or any kind of web-style communication. Use regular filesystem pathnames as the push/pull paths for everything.

Comment: I understand that I can use the SMB share as the backend for remote pushes (like I could have used ssh or a hg server). What I do not know is how to make it so that a push to that environment triggers a `hg update` on that environment (when I have a server I do it via a hook on `changegroup` on the server's repo)

Comment: I don't understand: If you enable a hook in a repo, it will run whenever the hooked event occurs (e.g., changesets arriving to the repo). Whether it's running a server should be irrelevant. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK, say I have a repo at `\\srv\hg\test1`. It has a `.hg` directory, in which there is a `hgrc` file. Adding a `[hooks]` section to that file with `changegroup = hg update` would trigger an update when an incoming push arrives (in other words, when I push my commits from my client to that repo). But then what/who would actually do the update? The `hg update` command needs to be run on the server so that the update is done on local (server) files.

Comment: This is the repo that is exposed by the webserver, right? When you push to an hg repo, you _change its state._ This requires code to be run behind the scenes: You update internal records, and you can run hooks. The whole repo _is_ on the server, so the hook will run on your machine and the result will be on the server. Have you tried what you describe? If you have, what happened?

Comment: Alex: I have updated (`EDIT 1`) my initial post to make my last findings following your comments easier to read. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your comments indicate some confusion: A disk is just storage. You can mount it on multiple machines (as a network share), and any of these machines can run programs off of it. Regarding your problem: On your workstation, assign a drive letter to the share.

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you from mount your Samba share and run `hg init` there?  You don't need mercurial server (`hg serve` or more sophisticated things) to perform push/pull operations.

Comment: I need to have a collaborative space (several users working on a file) where the files are used in production (and therefore I want a push to trigger an update)